# Javascript popup closes a second after it opens

Tags: javascript, html

I have two popups for logging in and registering, both open up fine on their own. But when I click on 'already a member?' link to close that popup and open the other, the other opens for a split second and then disappears.

```js
document.getElementById('not-member').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.popup-login').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.popup-register').style.display = 'flex';
});

document.getElementById('already-member').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.popup-register').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.popup-login').style.display = 'flex';
});
```

```html
<p>Not yet a member? <a id="not-member" href="">Sign Up</a></p>
<p>Already a member? <a id="already-member" href="">Sign In</a></p>
```

Does anyone know how I can get it so that when clicked the other popup opens and stays open and the original popup disappears? Cheers

Comment: Your JavaScript refers to elements that you don't have in your HTML.

Comment: If your goal is to have something to click that activates some JavaScript code, use a `span` element, not a hyperlink. Hyperlinks are for navigation, not simple JavaScript hooks. And, this is most likely the cause of your issue since you aren't actually disabling the native behavior of the link with `href=""`.

Comment: href="" + # = href="#"

Comment: How would I go about using <span> elements to do that? @ScottMarcus Thanks

Comment: Simply replace `<a id="not-member" href="">Sign Up</a>` with `<span id="not-member">Sign Up</span>`. You can then style the `span` to appear as if it were a hyperlink.

Comment: Okay that's great, thanks